# Is it possible to change the properties of a WebReference in run-time?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asmx, web-reference

I am trying to come up with such a solution that the user is going to enter the URL of a web-service and it is going to be tested.

Although what I want is a URL change, I guarantee the Service Description is always going to be the same (except the wsdl:service tag of course which contains the soap:address); I just want to test different customers, running the same service.

Comment: This is the first question I've asked at SO. It dates back to 17 Oct 2008. The question that is said to be asked before is asked on 8 Jun 2010. I think this question is not duplicate, the other one is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes you can. just change the url property of the service proxy before calling any methods on it.

Comment: Oh, my. All I needed was an instance, what I was looking at was the type.

Answer (score 3):

Yes; every web-service proxy offers a way to do this; with pre-WCF proxies (including WSEx) the address is the `Url` property on the proxy class - just change it before you do anything interesting with the proxy.

With WCF, I believe you specify the endpoint-address via one of the constructors.

So just generate your proxy from your reference wsdl, and off you go ;-p