# How do I change the URL of my web service?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, asmx, web-reference

If I change the url in the web.config file will the change be reflected in the .disco, .discomap, and .wsdl files that are in the WebReferences folder?

[Edit]

I'm using asp.net 2005

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the properties of a WebReference in run-time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211510/is-it-possible-to-change-the-properties-of-a-webreference-in-run-time)

Answer (score 2):

The change will not, as far as I'm aware, be reflected in all the other files. However, if you change the URL in web.config, your application will call the web service from the new URL at run-time. Check out this [blog entry](https://web.archive.org/web/20200808124012/http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2006/10/10/93654.aspx). (No, it's not one of mine!)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean in the client, set the [Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.webclientprotocol.url.aspx) property at execution time. You can configure this from anywhere you want, so long as you have access to the value at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

As I can remember **WSDL** file contains the **binding**(s) (URL mappings) of your WS. So if you change the URL on your machine (in WSDL, Disco, etc.) that's enough.

On the other hand don't forget to **regenerate client proxies**. They have to reflect WSDL changes.