# Can I change a web service reference URL in the Config file?

Tags: winforms, web-services, asmx, web-reference

I have an application targeting the 2.0 .NET framework. The solution is using the VS web service reference folder. A grep through the solution reveals that this URL lives in a handful of files. However in the deployed application a search shows that the URL lives in only the .config. So what happened to the .disco and .wsdl? Are they compiled into the .exe? Basically, I need to update the URL and I need to know if this requires a new build.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the properties of a WebReference in run-time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211510/is-it-possible-to-change-the-properties-of-a-webreference-in-run-time)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can change the URL that's being referenced at runtime.

If it's in a .config file, <strike>IIS will</strike> your app should detect the change in the .config file and load the new value. If not, then you'd have to restart the client. <strike>Perhaps you can stop and start the Web Site in IIS.</strike>

Further, you can definitely WRITE your code to read from a .config file.

```
  var myWS = new MyWebService();
  myWS.Url = WebServiceURL;
  myWS.SomeMethod();                     

private static string WebServiceURL { 
   get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyWebServiceURL"].ToString(); }           }
```

Meanwhile in your `.config` file, you have:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MyWebServiceURL" value="http://blah/foo/bar.asmx" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: @pcampbell: It make sense to me.

Comment: I'm talking about the client application's config to point to the correct URL. Not the web service running at the server. Why would i reset IIS?

Comment: I had the scenario in mind of a web app picking up the setting from the .config file.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the url in the web config (if the webservice remains unaltered. Not so sure if the webService as changed)